# How to efficiently store and retrieve parameters/arguments used during data processing in lists

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I work with a large count table and for my analyses it is usually required to split this table into subsets based on observations, variables, values or context information.

```r
# generating toy data
count_df1 <- data.frame(
  column1 = c(1:50),
  column2 = runif(50, 1, 10),
  column3 = runif(50, 1, 10)
)

count_df2 <- data.frame(
  column1 = c(1:50),
  column2 = runif(50, 1.5, 9),
  column3 = runif(50, 1.5, 9)
)

list_count_df <- list(count_df1 = count_df1, count_df2 = count_df2)
```

I learned to use lists and for loops to process all resulting subsets in the same manner. I'm rather using `for loops` than `apply` because I use the names of the objects (with the use of counters) to keep track of how I modified them and I don't know how to do this with e.g. `lapply`.

```
# set values to iterate over
thresholds <- c(2, 4)
conditions <- c(TRUE, FALSE)

# perform some kind of subsetting and store the parameters used
output_list <- list()
counter <- 0
for (current_threshold in thresholds) {
  for (count_df in list_count_df) {
    counter <- counter + 1
    # modify the name to keep track of changes
    current_name <- paste(names(list_count_df)[counter], current_threshold, sep = "_")
    output_list[[current_name]] <- subset(count_df1, column2 < current_threshold)
  }
  counter <- 0
}
```

Additionally, the time consuming part is usually the main function of the body, so a loop with a reduced overhead by apply would probably not safe so much time (I'm still open to this).

After I'm done with preparing the various subsets and subject them to the analysis, I need to store the analysis' results and the accompanying parameters for the different subsets. That is probably a common task.

```r
# allocate for df to store the results
result_length <- length(output_list) * length(conditions)
df_headers <- c("Names", "Threshold", "Input_table", "Standard_deviation", "Scaling")
df_results <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(df_headers), 
    nrow = result_length)), df_headers)

# perform some analyses (here: PCA) on the dfs while looping over 
# analysis parameters and storing some results directly
iii <- 0
table_counter <- 0
  for (item in output_list) {
  table_counter <- table_counter + 1
    for (condition in conditions) {  
      iii <- iii + 1
      current_name <- paste(names(output_list)[table_counter], condition, sep = "_")
      tmp <- prcomp(item, scale = condition)
      # let's pretend we are only interested in standard deviation per item
      df_results[iii, 1] <- current_name
      df_results[iii, 4] <- tmp$sdev[1]
      rm(tmp)
  }
}
```

However, I'm partly doing this by extracting parts of the name of the object, which is highly repetitive and also very custom and has to be changed for each additional step included beforehand. As I want to start my own package soon, this is nothing another user could easily follow.

```r
# extract more values from the name of the former object
df_results$Threshold <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(as.character(df_results$Names), '_'), "[", 3))
df_results$Input_table <- as.factor(sapply(strsplit(as.character(df_results$Names), '_'), "[", 2))
df_results$Scaling <- as.factor(sapply(strsplit(as.character(df_results$Names), '_'), "[", 4))
df_results
# now I could this into long format, do plotting etc
```

I provided a short example below of how such a workflow could look like. My questions are:

1) What are the general good practices on how to store parameters used for and how to extract them after processing?

2) If the solution is too case-specific for a general approach:

a) any ideas what to change here?

b) Are lists and/or for loops the way to go at all?

I do it because modifying names in `lapply` is unclear to me and without this I lose track of what is what. I also would not know how to efficiently handle all these different subsets in one big data.frame

Please consider that my original data contains numerical, factor and character columns with 100s of rows/observations and ten thousands of columns/variables.

Comment: Perhaps you could construct a parameters data file (eg CSV) which relates each of the named tables to its parameters, and pull from that for your processing. You might also look into `purrr`, which gives some simple, robust, readable methods for iteration.  https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly there are many ways to do this and it will come down to personal preference. One common way would be to define a class object that will set the standard of how you access information on it. Creating a class means that you can make S3 methods too. This could help give more flexibility on how you generate your class depending on if you are working on a list, df, or just a vector.

```
generate_foo <- function(x, ...){ 
  UseMethod("generate_foo")}
generate_foo.default <- function(x, current_threshold, conditions, name = NULL){
  if(is.null(name)){
    name <- as.character(substitute(x))
  }
  x <- x[x[["column2"]]<current_threshold,]
  tmp <- tryCatch({prcomp(x, scale = conditions)}, error=function(er){return("Error")})
  retval <- list(list(subset = x,
                 pcaObj = tmp, #could store the entire object or just the parts you care about.
                 subsetparam = current_threshold,
                 condition = conditions,
                 name = name))
  class <- "foo"
  return(retval)
}


generate_foo.list <- function(x,
                              current_threshold,
                              conditions, name = NULL){

  if(is.null(name)||length(name)!=length(x)){
    name <- names(x)
  }
  #Generate combinations
  combi <- separate( #generate all the possible combination indexes at once
    data.frame(
      indx = levels(suppressWarnings(interaction(1:length(x),
                                                 1:length(current_threshold),
                                                 1:length(conditions))))),
    col = "indx", into = c("df","thresh","cond"), sep = "\\.")
  x <- x[as.numeric(combi$df)]
  name <- name[as.numeric(combi$df)]
  current_threshold <- current_threshold[as.numeric(combi$thresh)]
  conditions <- conditions[as.numeric(combi$cond)]
  foolist <- mapply(FUN = generate_foo.default,
                    x = x,
                    current_threshold = current_threshold,
                    conditions = conditions,
                    name = name)
  class(foolist) <- "foolist"
  return(foolist)
}
```

With this method when you call:

```
foo <- generate_foo(x = list_count_df,
                    current_threshold = thresholds,
                    conditions = conditions,
                    name = c("Custname1","Custname2"))
```

You will end up with a list of objects with class `"foo"`. Specifically in this case the resulting object is length 8, each containing 5 parameters, `subset`, `pcaObj`, `subsetparam`, `condition`, `name`. with the exception of `pcaObj` sometimes throwing an error if the subset is too small, a `tryCatch` loop prevents the code from failing.
take it a step further by writing custom `print` and `summary` functions!

```
#summary
summary.foolist <- function(x){
  subsetdim <- unlist(lapply(x, function(y){prod(dim(y[["subset"]]))}))
  pcasdev <- unlist(lapply(x, function(y){y[["pcaObj"]]$sdev[1]}))
  subsetparam <- unlist(lapply(x, function(y){y[["subsetparam"]]}))
  condition <- unlist(lapply(x, function(y){y[["condition"]]}))
  name <- unlist(lapply(x,function(y){y[["name"]]}))
  df <- data.frame(SubsetDim=subsetdim, PCAsdev=pcasdev, SubsetParam=subsetparam, condition=condition, name = name)
  return(df)
}

summary(foo)
  SubsetDim   PCAsdev SubsetParam condition      name
1        24  1.207833           2      TRUE Custname1
2         6  1.732051           2      TRUE Custname2
3        54  1.324284           4      TRUE Custname1
4        33  1.372508           4      TRUE Custname2
5        24 16.258848           2     FALSE Custname1
6         6 12.024556           2     FALSE Custname2
7        54 15.592938           4     FALSE Custname1
8        33 14.057929           4     FALSE Custname2
```

Using a convention like this ensures your data is stored in a canonical way. Of course there are many ways you can choose to build your custom R class and object.

You could make one function that makes a list of subsetted dataframes and set that as one class. Then make another function that performs the analysis and generates a new class object. As long as you stick to building a named list, then accessing parts of the object become easier because they are organized.

Answer (score 1):

## Functional solution

### 0. Generate source data frame

```
# for reproducibility of random tasks
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(
    col1 = c(1:100),
    col2 = c(runif(50,1,10), runif(50,11,20)),
    col3 = c(runif(50,1,10), runif(50,11,20))
)
# so half of the rows have numbers 1 to 10 in col2 and col3
# and other have 11 to 20 in col2 and col3.

# let's randomize the order of rows
df <- df[sample(1:100),]
# and take this data frame `df` as our source data frame
# fromw which we will do the analysis.
```

### 1. Problem description

We want to subdivide the original df into sub data frames
applying 2 different criteria.

Then, we analyze each sub data frame
using all possible combinations of 2 different parameters,
finally, collect all analysis values and aggravate them to a data frame.

The criteria:

- criterium1: if col2 value is <= 10, we assign to the row "df1" therwise "df2".

  - categories `c("df1", "df2")`.
- criterium2: if col3 value is lower first limit, the row is assigned 'class5'
            if col3 value is > first limit but <= second limit, assign 'class15'
            other cases don't interest us - let's assign 'other'

  - categories `c("class5", "class15", "other")` # each row will be subdivided into 
    one of them

We want for each combination of the two criteria an own sub-dataframe
on which the analysis should be done.

The parameters for the analysis:

- parameter1: `'scale.=' c(TRUE, FALSE)`

  - parameter_categories `c("sc+", "sc-")`
- parameter2: `'center=' c(TRUE, FASE)`

  - parameter_categories `c("cen+", "cen-")`

The analysis result value:

- We want for each combination of the two parameters an own report or the value
  for 'Standard deviation'.

  - 3 stddev columns of the PC1, PC2, PC3

Additional information to be collected:

- we want a distinguishable (unique) name for each combination

### 2. How the entire analysis will look like:

```
# 0. categorize and split data frame
categories1 <- c("df1", "df2")[cut(df[, "col2"], c(1, 11, 20, Inf))]
categories2 <- c("class5", "class15", "other")[cut(df[, "col3"], c(-Inf, 5, 15, Inf))]

dfs <- split(df, gsub("class", "", paste(categories1, categories2, sep="_")))

# 1. Declare parameters and prepare all parameter combinations
parameters1 <- list("scale." = TRUE, "scale."=FALSE)
np1 <- c("scpos", "scneg")
parameters2 <- list("center"=TRUE, "center"=FALSE)
np2 <- c("cpos", "cneg")

params_list <- named_cross_combine(parameters1, parameters2, np1, np2, sep="_")

# 2. Apply analysis over all sub dfs and parameter combinations
#    and extract and aggravate analysis results into a final data frame
df_final <- apply_extract_aggravate(
    dfs=dfs,
    params=params_list,
    analyzer_func=prcomp,
    extractor_func=function(x) x$sdev,   # extractor must return a vector
    col_names=c("df", "limits", "scale", "center", "std_PC1", "std_PC2", "std_PC3"),
    sep="_"                              # separator for names
)

# 3. rename parameter column contents
df_final$scale <- unlist(lookup(df_final$scale, np1, parameters1))
df_final$center <- unlist(lookup(df_final$center, np2, parameters2))
```

`df_final`:

```
                      df limits scale center   std_PC1   std_PC2   std_PC3
df1_15_scpos_cpos    df1     15  TRUE   TRUE  1.205986 0.9554013 0.7954906
df1_15_scpos_cneg    df1     15  TRUE  FALSE  1.638142 0.5159250 0.2243043
df1_15_scneg_cpos    df1     15 FALSE   TRUE 15.618145 2.4501942 1.3687843
df1_15_scneg_cneg    df1     15 FALSE  FALSE 31.425246 5.9055013 1.7178626
df1_5_scpos_cpos     df1      5  TRUE   TRUE  1.128371 1.0732246 0.7582659
df1_5_scpos_cneg     df1      5  TRUE  FALSE  1.613217 0.4782639 0.4108470
df1_5_scneg_cpos     df1      5 FALSE   TRUE 13.525868 2.5524661 0.9894493
df1_5_scneg_cneg     df1      5 FALSE  FALSE 30.007511 3.9094993 1.6020638
df2_15_scpos_cpos    df2     15  TRUE   TRUE  1.129298 1.0069030 0.8431092
df2_15_scpos_cneg    df2     15  TRUE  FALSE  1.720909 0.1523516 0.1235295
df2_15_scneg_cpos    df2     15 FALSE   TRUE 14.061532 2.4172787 1.2348606
df2_15_scneg_cneg    df2     15 FALSE  FALSE 80.543382 3.8409639 1.8480111
df2_other_scpos_cpos df2  other  TRUE   TRUE  1.090057 0.9588241 0.9446865
df2_other_scpos_cneg df2  other  TRUE  FALSE  1.718190 0.1881516 0.1114570
df2_other_scneg_cpos df2  other FALSE   TRUE 15.168160 2.5579403 1.3354016
df2_other_scneg_cneg df2  other FALSE  FALSE 82.297724 5.0580949 1.9356444
```

### 3. Explanation step by step

#### 3.1 Declare Helper functions

```
# for preparing parameter combinations as lists

named_cross_combine <- function(seq1, seq2, seq1_names, seq2_names, sep="_") {
    res <- list()
    i <- 1
    namevec <- c()
    for (j1 in seq_along(seq1)) {
        for (j2 in seq_along(seq2)) {
            res[[i]] <- c(seq1[j1], seq2[j2])
            namevec[i] <- paste0(seq1_names[j1], sep, seq2_names[j2])
            i <- i + 1
        }
    }
    names(res) <- namevec
    res
}
# correctly named params list - `sep=` determines how names are joined
# you can apply `gsub()` on the namevec before assignment to adjust further the names.

# useful for doing analysis

do.call2 <- function(fun, x, rest) {
    do.call(fun, c(list(x), rest))
}

apply_parameters <- function(funcname, 
                             dfs, 
                             params) {
    lapply(dfs, function(df) lapply(params_list, function(pl) do.call2(funcname, df, pl)))
}

split_names_to_data_frame <- function(names_vec, sep) {
    res <- lapply(names_vec, function(s) strsplit(s, sep)[[1]])
    df  <- Reduce(rbind, res)
    # colnames(df) <- col_names
    rownames(df) <- names_vec
    df
}

apply_to_subdf_and_combine <- function(
     res_list,
     accessor_func=function(x) x,             # subdf result
     subdf_level_combiner_func=as.data.frame, # within subdf result
     combine_prepare_func=function(x) x,      # applied on each subdf result
     final_combiner_func=rbind,               # combine the results
     col_names=NULL,                          # column names for final
     sep="_") {                               # joiner for names
    res_accessed_combined <- lapply(res_list, 
                  function(x) do.call(what=subdf_level_combiner_func, 
                                      list(lapply(x, accessor_func))))
    res_prepared <- lapply(res_accessed_combined, combine_prepare_func)
    res_df <- Reduce(final_combiner_func, res_prepared)
    rownames(res_df) <- paste(unlist(sapply(names(res_prepared), rep, nrow(res_prepared[[1]]))),
                           unlist(sapply(res_prepared, rownames)),
                           sep = sep)
    names_df <- split_names_to_data_frame(rownames(res_df), sep = sep)
    final_df <- as.data.frame(cbind(names_df, res_df))
    if (!is.null(col_names)) {
        colnames(final_df) <- col_names
    }
    final_df
}

# for simplifying the function call
extract_and_combine <- function(res_list,
                                result_extractor_func,
                                col_names,
                                sep="_") {
    apply_to_subdf_and_combine(
        res_list = res_list,
        accessor_func = result_extractor_func,
        subdf_level_combiner_func=as.data.frame,
        combine_prepare_func=function(x) as.data.frame(t(x)),
        final_combiner_func=rbind,
        col_names=col_names,
        sep=sep
    )
}

# for even more simplifying function call
apply_extract_aggravate <- function(dfs,
                                    params,
                                    analyzer_func,
                                    extractor_func,
                                    col_names,
                                    sep="_") {
    extract_and_combine(
        res_list=apply_parameters(funcname=analyzer_func, dfs=dfs, params=params),
        result_extractor_func=extractor_func,
        col_names=col_names,
        sep=sep
    )
}


# useful for renaming the data frame columns values

lookup <- function(x, seq1, seq2) {
    seq2[sapply(x, function(x) which(x == seq1))]
}
```

#### 3.2 Categorize and split data frame

```
categories1 <- c("df1", "df2")[cut(df[, "col2"], c(1, 11, 20, Inf))]
categories2 <- c("5", "15", "other")[cut(df[, "col3"], c(-Inf, 5, 15, Inf))]

dfs <- split(df, gsub("class", "", paste(categories1, categories2, sep="_")))
```

But to have full control over categorization, you can 
declare your own categorizer functions and categorize and
split the data frame:

```
# write rules for criterium1 1 element as function
categorizer1 <- function(x) {
    if (1 <= x && x <= 10) {
        "df1"
    } else if (11 <= x && x <= 20) {
        "df2"
    }
}
# vectorize it to be able to apply it on entire columns
categorizer1 <- Vectorize(categorizer1)

# do the same for critreium2
categorizer2 <- function(x) {
    if (x <= 5) {
        "class5"
    } else if (5 < x && x <= 15) {
        "class15"
    } else {
        "other"
    }
}
categorizer2 <- Vectorize(categorizer2)

# apply on col2 and col3 the corresponding categorizers
categories1 <- categorizer1(df[,"col2"])
categories2 <- categorizer2(df[,"col3"])

# get the list of sub data frames according to categories
dfs <- split(df, gsub("class", "", paste(categories1, categories2, sep="_")))

# Let the categorizer functions return strings and
# for the second argument use `paste()` with `sep=` to determine
# how the names should be combined - here with "_".
# Use `gsub(pattern, replacement, x, ignore.case=F, perl=T)`
# to process the name using regex patterns to how you want it at the end.
# Here, we remove the bulky "class".
```

#### 3.3 Declare parameters as lists and their corresponding names in filename

```
parameters1 <- list("scale." = TRUE, "scale."=FALSE)
np1 <- c("scpos", "scneg")

parameters2 <- list("center"=TRUE, "center"=FALSE)
np2 <- c("cpos", "cneg")

# prepare all combinations of them in a list of lists
params_list <- named_cross_combine(parameters1, parameters2, np1, np2, sep="_")
# this produces a list of all possible parameter combination lists.
# Each parameter combination has to be kept itself in a list, because
# `do.call()` later requires the parameters being in a list.
# `named_cross_combine()` takes care of correct naming, 
# joining the names using `sep` values.
# The first element in `parameter1` is taken and is paired with each of 
# `parameters2`. Then the second of `parameter1` through all `parameters2`, etc.
```

#### 3.4 Apply all parameters over `dfs` and collect the results into a data frame

```
df_final <- apply_extract_aggravate(
    dfs=dfs,
    params=params_list,
    analyzer_func=prcomp,
    extractor_func=function(x) x$sdev,   # extractor must return a vector
    col_names=c("df", "limits", "scale", "center", "std_PC1", "std_PC2", "std_PC3"),
    sep="_"                              # separator for names
)

# This function takes the dfs and the parameters list and runs the
# analyzer_func, here `prcomp()` over all combinations of boths.
# The `extractor_func` must be chosen in a way that the returned result is a vector.
# If it is already a vector, set here `function(x) x` the identity function.
# The column names should give new names to the resulting columns.
# The number of the names are determined by:
# - the number of categoriesN,
# - the number of parametersN,
# - the number of elements of result after extractor_func() was applied.
# `sep=` determines which joiner is used for joining the names.
```

#### 3.5 Finally, rename parameter columns' contents by using `lookup()` + previously declared parameter lists (`parametersN`) with their corresponding name vectors (`npN`)

```
df_final$scale <- unlist(lookup(df_final$scale, np1, parameters1))
df_final$center <- unlist(lookup(df_final$center, np2, parameters2))
# Two parameter columns, so two commands.
```

This converts `df_final` from this:

```
#                       df limits scale center   std_PC1   std_PC2   std_PC3
# df1_15_scpos_cpos    df1     15 scpos   cpos  1.205986 0.9554013 0.7954906
# df1_15_scpos_cneg    df1     15 scpos   cneg  1.638142 0.5159250 0.2243043
# df1_15_scneg_cpos    df1     15 scneg   cpos 15.618145 2.4501942 1.3687843
# df1_15_scneg_cneg    df1     15 scneg   cneg 31.425246 5.9055013 1.7178626
# df1_5_scpos_cpos     df1      5 scpos   cpos  1.128371 1.0732246 0.7582659
# df1_5_scpos_cneg     df1      5 scpos   cneg  1.613217 0.4782639 0.4108470
# df1_5_scneg_cpos     df1      5 scneg   cpos 13.525868 2.5524661 0.9894493
# df1_5_scneg_cneg     df1      5 scneg   cneg 30.007511 3.9094993 1.6020638
# df2_15_scpos_cpos    df2     15 scpos   cpos  1.129298 1.0069030 0.8431092
# df2_15_scpos_cneg    df2     15 scpos   cneg  1.720909 0.1523516 0.1235295
# df2_15_scneg_cpos    df2     15 scneg   cpos 14.061532 2.4172787 1.2348606
# df2_15_scneg_cneg    df2     15 scneg   cneg 80.543382 3.8409639 1.8480111
# df2_other_scpos_cpos df2  other scpos   cpos  1.090057 0.9588241 0.9446865
# df2_other_scpos_cneg df2  other scpos   cneg  1.718190 0.1881516 0.1114570
# df2_other_scneg_cpos df2  other scneg   cpos 15.168160 2.5579403 1.3354016
# df2_other_scneg_cneg df2  other scneg   cneg 82.297724 5.0580949 1.9356444
```

to this:

```
                      df limits scale center   std_PC1   std_PC2   std_PC3
df1_15_scpos_cpos    df1     15  TRUE   TRUE  1.205986 0.9554013 0.7954906
df1_15_scpos_cneg    df1     15  TRUE  FALSE  1.638142 0.5159250 0.2243043
df1_15_scneg_cpos    df1     15 FALSE   TRUE 15.618145 2.4501942 1.3687843
df1_15_scneg_cneg    df1     15 FALSE  FALSE 31.425246 5.9055013 1.7178626
df1_5_scpos_cpos     df1      5  TRUE   TRUE  1.128371 1.0732246 0.7582659
df1_5_scpos_cneg     df1      5  TRUE  FALSE  1.613217 0.4782639 0.4108470
df1_5_scneg_cpos     df1      5 FALSE   TRUE 13.525868 2.5524661 0.9894493
df1_5_scneg_cneg     df1      5 FALSE  FALSE 30.007511 3.9094993 1.6020638
df2_15_scpos_cpos    df2     15  TRUE   TRUE  1.129298 1.0069030 0.8431092
df2_15_scpos_cneg    df2     15  TRUE  FALSE  1.720909 0.1523516 0.1235295
df2_15_scneg_cpos    df2     15 FALSE   TRUE 14.061532 2.4172787 1.2348606
df2_15_scneg_cneg    df2     15 FALSE  FALSE 80.543382 3.8409639 1.8480111
df2_other_scpos_cpos df2  other  TRUE   TRUE  1.090057 0.9588241 0.9446865
df2_other_scpos_cneg df2  other  TRUE  FALSE  1.718190 0.1881516 0.1114570
df2_other_scneg_cpos df2  other FALSE   TRUE 15.168160 2.5579403 1.3354016
df2_other_scneg_cneg df2  other FALSE  FALSE 82.297724 5.0580949 1.9356444
```

### 4. Final remarks

This is not very different from your approach. All information is collected in the names. And the names used for generating the part of the data frame which explains the background for the analysis data.
The `lookup()` function is very useful for renaming the columns for the parameters.

The categorization of a column can be very simplified by the `cat()` function. But in the `cut()` function you don't have full control over 
whether the upper/lower limit is included (`<=`) or not (`<`).
That is why sometimes declaring own categorizer functions can be of advantage. (And especially for more complex categorizations).

### Extensibility

- More categories: Just define more categories `categories1 categories2 categories3 ...`

```
# then do
dfs <- split(df, paste(categories1, categories2, categories3, ..., sep="_"))
# use `gsub()` around `paste()` or do
# names(dfs) <- gsub("search_term", "replace_term", names(dfs)) - over and over again
# until all names are as they should be.
```

- More parameters: Just define more `parametersN` - `npN` pairs.

```
# then do
params_list <- named_cross_combine(parameters1, parameters2, np1, np2, sep="_")
params_list <- named_cross_combine(params_list, parameters3, names(params_list), np3, sep="_")
params_list <- named_cross_combine(params_list, parameters4, names(params_list), np4, sep="_")
... (and so on ...)

# use then at the end more lines for renaming parameter column contents:
df_final[, prmcol_name1] <- unlist(lookup(df_final[, prmcol_name1], np1, parameters1))
df_final[, prmcol_name2] <- unlist(lookup(df_final[, prmcol_name2], np2, parameters2))
df_final[, prmcol_name3] <- unlist(lookup(df_final[, prmcol_name3], np2, parameters3))
... (and so on ...)
```

Thus, the number of categories and parameters is easily enhance-able.
The core helper functions stay the same. And don't have to be modified.

(The use of higher order functions (functions which take functions as arguments) as helper functions is key for their flexibility - one of the strenghs of functional programming).